# Filter NSDictionary by value using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I have a `NSDictionary` like so:

```
{
    1 = A;
    11 = AB;
    19 = ABC;
    2 = ABCD;
    3 = ABCDE;
    4 = ABCDEF;
    5 = ABCDEFG;
    6 = ABCDEFGH;
    7 = ABCDEFGHI;
    9 = ABCDEFGHIJ;
}
```

Now I want to filter the Dictionary with a predicate to return an array where the value begins e.g. with "ABCD".
The Key is an ID (string) and Value is of type string.

So the result should be

```
{
    ABCD;
    ABCDE;
    ABCDEF;
    ABCDEFG;
    ABCDEFGH;
    ABCDEFGHI;
    ABCDEFGHIJ;
}
```

How does the `NSPredicate` has to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Predicate will look like this:

```
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF BEGINSWITH[c] %@", @"ABCD"];
```

Comment: thanks for the fast answer. Is there even a way to get a filtered Dictionary back, instead of an array?

Comment: This is another question:) I think is possible only by iteration through all elements not with predicate